# How to put multiple selectors in one xml file and reference them from layout xml file?

Tags: android-layout

I have a layout file with 6 image buttons. Each button should show
different source image based selection/focus/noselection. I am able to
do this with 6 xml files under drawable folder with selector
nodes.

Is there a way to put all these selector nodes in ONE xml file to
accomplish the same. Less files means less management...

Answer (score -2):

Yes but you must manage it from the code with:

```
public class MyClass extend Activity implements OnSelect,OnFocus
```

if you use eclipse write "On" and click ctrl+spaceBar and select what you need and change the icon with myButtonName.src="@drawble/myimageonselect"

Comment: What you said ----"if you use eclipse write "On" and click ctrl+spaceBar and select what you need and change the icon with myButtonName.src="@drawble/myimageonselect" I cannot get it

Comment: after write "implements" write "On" and click crtl+spaceBar and you must see a list of comand now click on onselected, after eclispe send you an error you click on your class name and you must see another list and click on the first think and automatly it create a method and write inside the code to change the icon src